# flutter run -bash: Desktop/flutter/bin/flutter: No such file or directory

Tags: flutter

flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G103, locale pl-PL)
[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from:
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK
      components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup
      for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set
      ANDROID_SDK_ROOT to that location.
      You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.2.1)
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

I created a my_app folder and typed:

```
cd my_app 
flutter run
```

The "flutter run" command does not work. How to fix this?

Comment: It is clearly saying in your `flutter doctor` summary, **✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.**. Please follow the instructions, and everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed android sdk?
If not then installing Android Studio will will install all the required dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem it easy to solve

1. Open Android Studio
2. And go to preference
3. Plugins
4. Download flutter & dart

Answer (score 0):

You need Android SDK, if you plan on using Android Studio then SDK will be downloaded with the Android Studio

https://developer.android.com/studio is the link to download